# Symfony : Pagination with inner join

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, pagination

I need to implement a pagination. Seemingly, Doctrine doesn't support some jointures.

Here is my query :

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
              ->createQueryBuilder();

$query->setFirstResult(($page - 1) * $maxperpage);
$query->setMaxResults($maxperpage);

$query->select('d')
      ->from('DemandeBundle:Declaration', 'd')
      ->orderBy('d.id', 'ASC')
      ->innerJoin('ContactBundle:Contact', 'c', 'WITH', 'd.contact = c')
      ->where('c.structure_id = :structure_id')
      ->setParameter('structure_id', $structureId)
      ->getQuery()
      ->getResult();

return new Paginator($query, true);
```

It's working fine when I am not using innerJoin but I need to use it so as to display only requests regarding to my user.

Using innerJoin I got that kind of error :

```
"An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template 
("Cannot count query which selects two FROM components, cannot make distinction") in   
DemandeBundle:Demande:listing_demande.html.twig at line 25"
```

How can I circumvent this problem without using another bundle or whatever.

Hope you will understand me guy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your `Declaration` somehow related to `Contact`?

It's far better for you to have `ManyToOne` relation in `Contact` that points to `Declaration`. That way, it will work since you won't have **two FROM components**, but single one instead.

Then, modify the query to do:

```
->innerJoin('d.contant', 'c')
```

The full query should look like this:

```
$query->select('d')
  ->from('DemandeBundle:Declaration', 'd')
  ->orderBy('d.id', 'ASC')
  ->innerJoin('d.contact', 'c') // <-- THIS LINE IS CRITICAL
  ->where('c.structure_id = :structure_id')
  ->setParameter('structure_id', $structureId)
  ->getQuery()
  ->getResult();
```

Comment: Yes Declaration is related to Contact by : 
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sga\ContactBundle\Entity\Contact", inversedBy="declarations", cascade={"persist", "merge"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="contact_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })

Comment: Excelent. Then it's just a matter of replacing the `innerJoin` line with one I wrote.

Comment: I've replaced mine by your but it's not working. it doesn't recognized c. It's normal it doesn't know which class is related to c.

Comment: $query->select('d')
      ->from('SgaDemandeBundle:Declaration', 'd')
      ->innerJoin('d.contact = c')
      ->where('c.structure_id = :structure_id')
      ->setParameter('structure_id', $structureId)
      ->orderBy('d.id', 'ASC')
      ->getQuery()
      ->getResult();
I got "[Syntax Error] line 0, col 68: Error: Expected end of string, got 'c'"

Comment: It's not `innerJoin('d.contact = c')`, but rather `innerJoin('d.contact', 'c')`. I have edited the answer to include full `QueryBuilder` construction...

Comment: I have a very similar situation but I don't have the option of using d.contact as the join. This is because there is no entity mapping between the join table and anything in the main query. Does anyone know a way to set the parent alias on the query builder?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found out a solution :

Instead of :

```
$query->select('d')
      ->from('DemandeBundle:Declaration', 'd')
      ->orderBy('d.id', 'ASC')
      ->innerJoin('ContactBundle:Contact', 'c', 'WITH', 'd.contact = c')
      ->where('c.structure_id = :structure_id')
      ->setParameter('structure_id', $structureId)
      ->getQuery()
      ->getResult();
```

I used :

```
$query->select('d')
      ->add('from', 'SgaDemandeBundle:Declaration d INNER JOIN d.contact c')
      ->where('c.structure_id = :structure_id')
      ->setParameter('structure_id', $structureId)
      ->orderBy('d.id', 'ASC')
      ->getQuery();
```